# Windows Phone 8.1 Datepicker show on click

Tags: c#, datepicker, windows-phone-8.1, menuitem

I've been stuck for couple of hours already finding how i can activate a datepickerDialog from clicking on a menu item.
I would like to link the clicked event of the button to the activation of the Datepickerpage.

Is this possible? what are my options ?

Thanks in advance!
[image: Button that activates the Datepicker]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using standard *DatePicker* then one way to do it may be (also completely in XAML) to use another *DatePickerFlyout* and bind its *Date*:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <DatePicker Date="{Binding ElementName=myDatePickerFlyout,Path=Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Setting">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <DatePickerFlyout x:Name="myDatePickerFlyout" />
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: I already tought i remembered you. a previous post of you about registering background tasks helped me yesterday by more than alot! 
My sincere thanks Romasz!